# Windows 7 RTM won't see wireless network

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

We have a wireless router that 5 Vista laptops and 1 XP laptop connect too. The router is set up for B & G wifi. We have a Windows 7 laptop that sees every other network in the building, except ours.

What would be preventing the Windows 7 laptop from seeing our network?

Rich

Comment: Still an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a driver error. Lenovo only provides XP drivers for my model, but I managed to install the Vista driver for the model abbove.

The laptop in question was a Lenovo s10e netbook.